# Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':_debugApkCopy' when using cordova-plugin-facebook4

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, cordova-cli

I installed cordova facebook4 plugin

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-facebook4 --save --variable APP_ID="12345678910" --variable APP_NAME="My Application Name"
```

and when I try to build, it shows
[this error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J41bi.png)

I never got this error till last week, but today when I want to update my app it shows that error. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a new issue with the facebook plugin.

Try changing

```
<framework src="com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4+"/>
```

to

```
<framework src="com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.26.0"/>
```

in `plugin.xml` of plugin located in `/plugins/cordova-plugin-facebook4`

and replace `com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+`
with
`com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.26.0`
both in `/platforms/android/build.gradle` and `/platforms/android/project.properties` in your cordova project.

This should be a temporary measure.

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio, go to SDK Manager and make sure:

- Android SDK Platorm 27 is installed
- Android SDK Build Tools 27.0.1 is installed
- Android SDK Platform Tools is up-to-date (27.0.0 or above)
- Android SDK Tools is up-to-date (26.1.1 or above)
- Android Support Library is up-to-date (23.2.1 or above)
- Android Support Repository is up-to-date (47.0.0 or above)